# Find a particular cell value and delete row afterwards excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm working on a program that reads an excel file and searches for a particular value in a sheet, lets say sheetname = "sheet3".

Afterwards, the program would look in a particular column, lets say column 'D', and searches for a data value in the whole column. If the data value exists, the whole row containing that data value would be deleted/hidden away.

Currently, i have managed to obtain the data value from the excel file of a column, but have not been able to carry on with the code. I have tried for about 3 days and to no avail. I would appreciate any help!

This is the code that I have tried currently:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string fileName =
            @"D:\test.xlsx";

            // Retrieve the value in cell D2.
            string value = GetCellValue(fileName, "Sheet3", "D2");

        }
        // Retrieve the value of a cell, given a file name, sheet name, 
        // and address name.
        public static string GetCellValue(string fileName,
            string sheetName,
            string addressName)
        {
            string value = null;

            // Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document =
                SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
            {
                // Retrieve a reference to the workbook part.
                WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

                // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use that 
                // Sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
                Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
                  Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

                // Throw an exception if there is no sheet.
                if (theSheet == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("sheetName");
                }

                // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
                WorksheetPart wsPart =
                    (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));

                // Use its Worksheet property to get a reference to the cell 
                // whose address matches the address you supplied.
                Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
                  Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();

                // If the cell does not exist, return an empty string.
                if (theCell != null)
                {
                    value = theCell.InnerText;

                    // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
                    // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
                    // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
                    // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
                    // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
                    // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
                    // the words TRUE or FALSE.
                    if (theCell.DataType != null)
                    {
                        switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
                        {
                            case CellValues.SharedString:

                                // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                                // shared strings table.
                                var stringTable =
                                    wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

                                // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                                // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                                // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                                // the table.
                                if (stringTable != null)
                                {
                                    value =
                                        stringTable.SharedStringTable
                                        .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                                }
                                break;

                            case CellValues.Boolean:
                                switch (value)
                                {
                                    case "0":
                                        value = "FALSE";
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        value = "TRUE";
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I have only tried OpenXML as the server that i am going to work on does not have any Microsoft Excel or any other software installed. Hence, Im not able to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to complete this task. Would appreciate any help regarding this matter please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use the NPOI library instead of OpenXML. NPOI is an open source library for reading and writing Microsoft Office documents without needing any office software installed. It is a .NET port of the Java POI library. You can find many samples online.

The following C# console program uses NPOI to do what you asked.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string FileName = @"d:\test.xlsx";
        IWorkbook workbook = OpenWorkBook(FileName);

        ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheet("Sheet3");
        HideRows(sheet);
        DeleteRows(sheet);

        SaveWorkBook(workbook, FileName);

        Console.WriteLine("Done. Press any key");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IWorkbook OpenWorkBook(string workBookName)
    {
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(workBookName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            return new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        }
    }

    private static void HideRows(ISheet sheet)
    {

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= sheet.LastRowNum; rowIndex++)
        {
            IRow row = sheet.GetRow(rowIndex);
            if (row == null) continue; // Completely unused row returns null
            ICell cell = row.GetCell(3); // 0-based column index: 0=column A, 1=B, etc
            if (cell != null && cell.StringCellValue == "HideMe")
            {
                row.Hidden = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteRows(ISheet sheet)
    {
        // When deleting we must iterate rows in reverse sequence
        for (int rowIndex = sheet.LastRowNum; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
        {
            IRow row = sheet.GetRow(rowIndex);
            if (row == null) continue;
            ICell cell = row.GetCell(3);
            if (cell != null && cell.StringCellValue == "DeleteMe")
            {
                // use ShiftRows to actually delete the row:
                sheet.ShiftRows(row.RowNum+1, sheet.LastRowNum, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SaveWorkBook(IWorkbook workbook, string workBookName)
    {
        string newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(workBookName, "new.xlsx");
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            workbook.Write(file);
        }

        string backupFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(workBookName, "bak.xlsx");
        File.Replace(newFileName, workBookName, backupFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help! I managed to get it working. The only problem i have is whenever I open the excel file after i run the program, i get an error that the excel file is broken - "Excel found unreadable content in "test.xlsx". May i know why is this so? Thank you so much

Comment: It might be a incompatibility with the particular version of Excel you are using. I tested with Excel 2013. I suggest you start with a workbook with only 1 sheet,  completely empty (change the program code to look for sheet1 instead of sheet3), and see you can open it after the program runs, then work up from there. Also, did you know, you can rename a .xlsx file to .zip and then unzip it: do that and compare before and after to get some clues.

Comment: Hi, okay sure. I will look into it. Thanks a lot!!